# Rails 4 - Redirect to Next Page with Javascript using Kaminari

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am currently using Kaminari for pagination, and I am aware of the `link_to_next_page` method.  However, I am currently looking to "link to the next page" within the pagination scope *after* a form has been processed and submitted.

In other words:

1. The user clicks the "submit" button
2. The form is submitted via `:remote => true`
3. Javascript programmatically directs the user to the next page.

Sort of like: 
    **create.js.erb**

```
  <% if @result %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href="<%= @user.next_page %>
    </script>
  <% end %>
```

Is it possible for me to generate/determine what the next page is and then redirect the user via javascript?

Thanks!

**Final solution:**
Based on Kieran's help below, here's what I ended up doing:

```
<% if @result %>   
  <% unless @users.last_page? %>
  window.location.href="?page=<%=@users.current_page+1 %>"
  <% else %>
      window.location.href="completed"
<% end %>
```

Which appears to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that Kaminari requires the "scope" in order to correctly ascertain the  next page from your current page:

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/bc51fd08f9e67b8338b421f6827d7d8e54c82deb/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb#L64

Since you are submitting to the javascript, you will need to provide this scope to this method to make it work. In your controller in your create method you will need to have the same code to query the object that you want paginated on and then let Kaminari do the rest.

```
@users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]
```

You will need to ensure that the form also sends along the `params[:page]`

Then you can do:

```
  <% if @result && !@users.last_page? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href="<%=  params.merge(param_name => (@users.current_page + 1)) %>"
    </script>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kieran.  `window.location.href="<%= link_to_next_page @users %>"` returns a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)` error.  When I change it to: `window.location.href="<%= link_to_next_page @users, "Next page" %>"`, it just refreshes the current page.

Comment: What is the @users in your controller for ``def create``?

Comment: It is: `@users = Users.where("group_id = ?", @group_id).page(params[:page]).per(1)`

Comment: Also, the `link_to_next_page` basically just generates HTML, like a link_to tag would do: `<a href="/controllers/create?page=2" rel="next">Next page</a>`.  I'm not sure how placing this inside `window.location.href=` would make it work anyhow.

Comment: I cant test it without installing it locally but I have updated my answer. You should put a binding.pry in the create.js and try and get the next page from the users object somehow.

Comment: Hi Kieran, I needed to modify it a bit.  Please look at my original post for what I ended up to (or similar to what I ended up using).  Thanks for your help.